# I'm a beginner to React Redux. Will I be able to get some suggestions to develop some sample apps to improve myself in the subject?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm a quite beginner to React and Redux..Will I be able to get some suggestions on some sample apps to develop to improve myself in the mentioned subject area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether you can get any sample project for the same. But if you want to learn, you can refer to the Udemy course [React - The Complete Guide (incl Hooks, React Router, Redux)](https://www.udemy.com/course/react-the-complete-guide-incl-redux/)

Everything is explained in simple terms. As of now, the prices are high. Just look for some sales (comes very often). You can get it for Rs 700 or even less.

Answer (score 0):

Many resources, free even for you to try. I would recommend using the official websites and just go with their tutorials to get a sense of how to make something small. That's how I started, some of them have interactive sample apps in CodePen or Sandbox. In Redux, for example, [a Counter with React](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/counter).

After that, it depends on what kind of application you want. On the official pages, they have example projects too:

- https://reactjs.org/community/examples.html
- https://redux.js.org/introduction/examples#examples

Doing a google search also has many example projects too.